# In which order where the Primarchs found by the Emperor?

Tags: warhammer-40k

The Primarchs were scattered through the galaxy by the Chaos Gods and then found one by one by the Emperor during the Great Crusade.

1. It is well-known that Horus was discovered first. This gave time to the Emperor and the future Warmaster to develop a deep bond.
2. We (at least me) learn at the beginning of *Wolfsbane* that Leman Russ was the second to be discovered.
3. I believed, and [Wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Primarch) also claims it (but without a source), that Alpharius was last to be found. However, I have a slight doubt about it since everything with the Alpha Legion is "shrouded in mysteries". Also, from Lexicanum,

> before [Alpharius](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Alpharius_Omegon)' discovery by the Emperor, members of the XXth Legion were already using the codename, as seen during the Rangdan Xenocides.

Does it mean that Alpharius had already been discovered by the Emperor but his discovery kept secret for a while?

4. According to Lexicanum, Magnus the Red was with the Emperor when [Lorgar](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Lorgar_Aurelian) was rediscovered.

**What other information on the order of rediscovery of the Primarchs do we have?**

I am looking for absolute (like "Leman Russ was the second to be discovered") or relative ("Magnus was discovered before Lorgar") information.

Comment: In the table on Lexicanum there is a column with the discovery order of each Primarch; missing the Lost Primarchs of couse - https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Primarch#Rediscovery

Comment: @Odin1806: I read that table many times but never noticed it! It was added last year, so I probably overlooked it. The link to the source does not seem to work. Have you seen it? Is it reliable?

Comment: I think I first noticed that new column a few months ago looking something up myself and the source didn't work when I tried it either...

Comment: i tweeted Laurie Goulding(black library) who is mentioned as the source for confirmation on the list, hopefully he answers.

Comment: He answered :), https://twitter.com/LaurieGoulding/status/1153686349871894529
So yeah it seems that @Odin1806 's link shows the chronological order of primarchs found.

Comment: https://twitter.com/LaurieGoulding/status/1153699041537998848 follow up tweet, so maybe he will give additional info at a later date.

Comment: @TerranGaming: great! You should write an answer, so I can accept it and award your efforts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Odin1806 mentioned https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Primarch#Rediscovery shows the chronological order of Primarchs being discovered.

TL;DR

Below are the primarchs numbered by legion, the number at the end signifying when discovered compared to their brothers.

I   Lion El'Jonson  The Lion 11

III Fulgrim The Phoenician  5

IV  Perturabo   The Lord of Iron 12

V   Jaghatai Khan   The Great Khan, The Warhawk 15

VI  Leman Russ  The Wolf King, The Great Wolf   2

VII Rogal Dorn  The Emperor's Champion, The Praetorian of Terra 7

VIII    Konrad Curze    The Night Haunter, The Lord of the Night    16

IX  Sanguinius  The Great Angel 10

X   Ferrus Manus    The Gorgon  4

XII Angron  The Red Angel, The Lord of the Red Sands    17

XIII    Roboute Guilliman   The Battle King, The Avenging Son   8

XIV Mortarion   The Death Lord, the Reaper of Men   13

XV  Magnus the Red  The Crimson King, The Red Cyclops   9

XVI Horus Lupercal  The Warmaster,  1

XVII    Lorgar Aurelian The Urizen, The Golden One  14

XVIII   Vulkan  The Lord of Drakes  6

XIX Corvus Corax    The Raven-Lord  18

XX  Alpharius Omegon    The Last Primarch, The Lord of Serpents 20

[Verified](https://twitter.com/LaurieGoulding/status/1153686349871894529) by Laurie Goulding writer and editor of a number of black library books who was kind enough to help. 
Should the author provide more information i will update this answer if appropriate.

Comment: added them just for you ;) @TheAurochs

Comment: Thanks for the list. So, Alpharius was really the last to be found. And the Primarchs that were executed were the third and second-to-last to be found. Interesting

Comment: @TerranGaming - Well down sir... it is always a shock to me when social media can be used for something more than posting selfies... this is much more important!

Comment: New lore has it that Alpharius may have been found first

Comment: This is not correct. In the primarch series (Alpharius: Head of the Hydra), Alpharius is the very first primarch found.

Comment: @Itération122442
Even though this answer was written before the alpharius book, information containing alpharius and when he was found is disputed by multiple in universe sources, as such I will take the confirmation of a gamesworkshop writer before the saying so of a known liar.

Comment: @TerranGaming I am confused. Who are you qualifying "a known liar" ?